# How to show percentage completion of local file crawling using Nutch?

Tags: nutch

I wonder, how to show the percentage of completion of local file crawling?

I am going to use Nutch to crawl a single shared disk.

Update:

What if I use "ls -R" or "find ~" to get all the filenames in advance, and store them as seed? In that way we know the total number of files.

Comment: Downvoter, mind to tell why down vote this question?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible due to the nature of Nutch.

Nutch crawls content by starting at a root node (the seed) and find any outlinks from it, crawling them iteratively until there are no more links or the crawl limit is reached.

As Nutch does not know the full count of the nodes to crawl, it is not possible to calculate a percentage.

You can find an overview of Nutch here: http://www.slideshare.net/digitalpebble/large-scale-crawling-with-apache-nutch

An alternative to monitor a Nutch crawl: https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/MonitoringNutchCrawls

EDIT:
I suppose you could get the indexed documents count out of SOLR, or write a plugin that increments a counter every time a file is crawled...

The bigger question is, what problem are you trying to solve?